# Making Word VBA make select word BOLD, UNDERLINE ETC

Tags: fonts, underline, bold

I have a macro that changes gender terms.  I would like for it BOLD, UNDERLINED and FONT SIZE = 20. I specify this below but nothing happens to the replace text in the document. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`your text`Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
`your text`Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
`your text`With Selection.Find
`your text` .Text = "[Mr./Ms.]"
`your text`.Replacement.Text = "Ms."
`your text` `your text`.Forward = True
`your text`.Font.Underline = True
`your text`.Font.Bold = True
`your text`.Font.Size = 20
`your text`.Wrap = wdFindContinue
`your text`.Format = False
`your text` .MatchCase = False
`your text`.MatchWholeWord = False
`your text`.MatchWildcards = False
`your text`.MatchSoundsLike = False
`your text` .MatchAllWordForms = False
`your text`End With
`your text`Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

I tried specifing orders of the form "font.underline, bold or font size = 20." This did not show up in the document when I ran the macro.